# Is there any way to cancel UrlRequest in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

Is there any way to cancel UrlRequest in Kivy?

```
def got_url(req, result):
    print(result)
req = UrlRequest('http://httpbin.org/delay/2', got_url)  # Request lasts 2 seconds

def my_callback(dt):
    print('Request cancelled.')
    # sort of req.cancel()
Clock.schedule_once(my_callback, 1)  # But some event happens after 1 sec. and I want to cancel request
```

This is just example: I know about timeout, I want to cancel request on some arbitrary event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik there's no other way except `UrlRequest.timeout`, which could translate to politely wait and close any harmful stuff safely. It uses `Thread` which may and may not be dangerous. Even more if e.g. packaged into exe or other form of binary where it could create a lock because something broke. I think the way you would like it to use would only trigger problems.

There's another way using `on_*` events and as small as possible `timeout`, which can trigger your function.

Example: set timeout for 1s if you want to cancel it after that amount of time and let the UrlRequest ping you when it does so, which is

1. safer to use than stopping it at random place
2. less amount of lines for reinventing the wheel